# Powershell how use jdbc driver to connect database

Tags: jdbc, db2, odbc, database-connection, powershell-3.0

I need to use a JDBC driver (JtOpen AS400) in my Powershell script to connect the DB2 database. Could you help me? I don't know how to write the connection string.

I have tried with ODBC driver but it doesn't work. I think my ODBC configuration is bad but I can't find the problem. I have also tried with a DB2 provider, but the installation is not complete. The provider is not added to the list, I don't know why.

There are other solutions?

Comment: Why do you think you can use a JDBC driver at all? JDBC is for Java, and PowerShell is not Java-based. Attempting to use a JDBC driver - assuming that is even possible - would probably require additional helper libraries and a convoluted setup. You would probably better off asking how to install or use the DB2 provider (assuming you're talking about a ADO.net provider), would probably make more sense.

Comment: To be able to use any ODBC type functionality, you need to have an ODBC-driver.  If (and only if) your Db2-database lives on an AS/400 (i-series), then you need to install and correctly configure the product "IBM i access for Windows". This gives (among other things) an ODBC option., which might allow integration with powershell odbc based cmdlets.    Whether there is an odbc-to-jdbc bridge (to harness jt400) is a different matter.

Comment: @mao Given the OP wants to connect from PowerShell, using an odbc-to-jdbc (or jdbc-to-odbc) bridge doesn't make a lot of sense, given PowerShell itself is not Java-based, you would then need something to bridge between PowerShell and JDBC.

Comment: A quick Google for "DB2 powershell" suggests multiple how-to's and tools (some of them commercial) to connect from PowerShell to DB2. I'd suggest investigating those before even trying to investigate using a JDBC driver from PowerShell.

Comment: What db2 client have you installed ?  Make sure you installed at least the **Data Server Driver Package**, or the **Data Server Client**  as these are the only ones that comes with .Net provider that can be used by powershell.